# Different controller actions for POST and GET requests at the same route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller, action

I want to route the same address, e.g., 'http://server/path' to different controller actions depending on the request type, whether it is a GET or POST request.

How can I do that in Rails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
get "/path" => "controller#get_action"
post "/path" => "controller#post_action"
```

Comment: what if we want to set the same custom path, via the `as:` option?

Answer (score 6):

I think you could do this:

```
match '/path' => 'controller#action', :via => :get
match '/path' => 'controller#another_action', :via => :post
```

Answer (score -1):

Generate a resource using the Rails scaffold and you'll see how it should be done:

```
./script/generate scaffold Person name:string
```

**EDIT**

Got downvoted so maybe I should expand my answer. The scaffold demonstrates how to build a RESTful resource. By convention, a POST will map to the create method in the controller, a GET will map to the index method (or the show method if an ID is present), etc. All you need add to your routes.rb is:

```
resources :people
```